# Best way to auto backup myphpadmin database (windows)

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, backup

I would like to setup a daily auto backup of my online myphpadmin database. The backup can be stored on my PC (which is turned on most days) or online somewhere (within myphpadmin somewhere?)

What is the easiest way to achieve this?
myphpadmin has an event scheduler, but requires SQL instructions - but I cant find the commands necessary to make this work.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This may depend on your hosting. But i solved it like this:

Create script, eg. backup.sh, with 777 rights, in some not publicly accessible folder

```
#!/bin/sh
#change directory to your backup directory
cd /home/xxx/backup_dbs/;
#get backup of database of applications
mysqldump --user='myuser' --password='mypw' mydb >tmp_db.sql;
#compress it in zip file
zip app_database-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M).sql.zip tmp_db.sql;
#remove  sql file
rm -rf tmp_db.sql;
#delete backups older than 20 days
find /home/xxx/backup_dbs/app* -mtime +20 -type f -delete;
```

and then schedule it via cron jobs

```
/home/xxx/backup_dbs/backup.sh
```

It does work on a VPS as well as another cheap reseller account i have. If it doesn't, maybe you just have to call up your hoster to activate execution of shell scripts for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
where do I call the script from?
777 rights? 
cron jobs?

Comment: Create a new file in your account with extension .sh (Shell/Bash Script). You should have a filemanager in your hosting account. If not, use FTP. DON'T place the file in your Website-Directory, where it could be reached via web, the same for the DB-Backup folder.  Then open it's properties and set the rights to 777 https://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-permissions-chmod-of-a-file

A Cron Job is a scheduled, repeatable commands. Most hosting accounts offer this. Look for it  in your administration (cpanel  for example). 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwpUjz1tMbA

Comment: Finally found the time to look at this. I'm using 000webhost. I have created a Cron job, which is set to run my specified script autoBackup.php daily... I'm using this query to test it...

$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";

However, I'm getting an "Access denied for user" error, even though I'm using credentials that I know work for other php scripts.

Any suggestions? I'm a little lost

Comment: I right-clicked the php file and clicked permissions. I have turned on the owner - execute permission... (I'm guessing this is the 777 rights you refer to?) (I'll test later today!)